# How to writing data into a csv file and save it on local device in android development?

Tags: java, android, csv, mobile

I am developing a chat app. I need to save the chat history into a csv file and save it on local device. Actually, I do not exactly know what is local device. I just know it does't mean SD card.

About writing a csv file, should this part of code insert in the chat content showing function or create a new class for it?

Thanks!

Here is the function of sending message:

```
public void onSendClick(View v){
    String msg= mInput.getText().toString().trim();
    if (msg.length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please input message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    mChatContent.add(mBluetoothAdapter.getName() + ":" + msg);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    TaskService.newTask(new Task(mHandler,Task.TASK_SEND_MSG, new Object[]{msg}));
    mInput.setText("");

}
```

Here is the message of receiving:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handlerMessage(Message msg){
        switch (msg.what){
            case Task.TASK_SEND_MSG:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg.obj.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Task.TASK_RECV_MSG:
                mChatContent.add(msg.obj.toString());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case Task.TASK_GET_REMOTE_STATE:
                setTitle(msg.obj.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

csv file

```
public void SaveToCsv(ArrayList<String> content, String name){//parameters means chat content and device name
    PrintWriter csvWriter;
    try
    {

        File file = new File(where should i save it);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file = new File(where should i save it);
        }
        csvWriter = new  PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));


        csvWriter.print(name+": "+content.toString());
        csvWriter.print("\r\n");
        csvWriter.close();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some of the code you're using, so that we could provide feedback/help based on that?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Well your code has nothing to do with saving text to a file. So where are we looking at?

Comment: I just knew how to save data to the csv, but I don't know how to decide its saving path.